# Dual display with final cut pro

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have a MacBook Pro 13” 2019, and until now I have used a single external monitor for Final Cut Pro x. I just bought a new monitor, and when I select the dual display in fcpx, the second screen goes to my mbp instead of the second screen.

Could anyone tell me how I can set the second display for fcpx to a different screen?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the system preferences, in the display arrange dialogue you will see a menu bar. Move this bar to the monitor representation you want FCPX to have its main window.